# Area between two spirals

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

I need to find the area between these two spirals given in the polar coordinates: 
$$r = e^{5 \theta}$$
$$r = e^{10 \theta}$$
$$0 \le \theta \le 3\pi$$
This seems to be quite simple, yet this problem is marked as "hard" and so I am 
not sure of the solution.

I think that it is enough to find the area between these two exp curves and then 'convert' this area into the polar coordinates.

The Jacobian is $r$.

The are will be

$$\int_{\theta = 0}^{\theta = 3 \pi} \int_{r = e^{5 \theta}}^{r = e^{10 \theta} } r drd\theta$$

Is my method a correct way to solve this?
If not, please, tell me where the mistake is before posting your own, different solution.

Comment: Make sure that the two spirals don't intersect underway, which they do when you replace $3\pi$ by $5\pi$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what is meant by "the area between the two spirals". The way you're interpreting it, you're closing off the area with a border between $(3\pi,\mathrm e^{5\cdot3\pi})$ and $(3\pi,\mathrm e^{10\cdot3\pi})$ and calculating the area of the resulting closed shape. But in a sense, the area between $r=\mathrm e^{10\theta}$ for $0\le\theta\le\pi$ and $r=\mathrm e^{5\theta}$ for $2\pi\le\theta\le3\pi$ is also "between the two spirals". So I think what's "hard" here is the interpretation of the question. Under your interpretation, your solution seems correct.